# onPictureInPictureModeChanged method can't detect PIP mode?

Tags: android

I'm testing PIP mode in android.

What am I trying to do is detecting PIP mode and do something.

My test code is:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pipButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:onClick="enterPipMode"
        android:text="@string/enter_pip_mode"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/videoView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode) {
    super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode);

    if(isInPictureInPictureMode) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.ebookfrenzy.videoplayer.VIDEO_INFO");

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Favorite Home Movie Clips", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        createPipAction();
    } else {
        binding.videoView1.setMediaController(mediaController);
        binding.pipButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(receiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the **onPictureInPictureModeChanged** method is not called when videoView1 switches to PIP mode. I searched the web and found the solution. After adding Congifuration type parameter to **onPictureInPictureModeChanged** method, **onPictureInPictureModeChanged** method was called successfully.

A. Doesn't work →
public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode)

B. Work →
public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode, **Configuration config**)

- When I used A, Android Studio didn't give me any errors. But method was not called.
- Is there a way to detect PIP mode switching even if I use A? Do I really need to use B?
- If I have to use B, what is the Configuration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue of Sdk version. I found below description in android development page.

```
onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode)
```

> This method was deprecated in API level 26. Use
> onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean,
> android.content.res.Configuration) instead.

And my minSdk version was 26. (targetSdk 32)

But don't know why Android Studio didn't alert when I used below version:

```
onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode)
```

Hope this helps.